# Cut command not working on linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying this:

`echo "This is test" | cut -f 1`

and it is not cutting anything, I get this:

`This is test`

Comment: Can any one give me the definitaion of real question. i didn't knew if cut uses `tab` as delimiter and i asked here. what else one can ask for

Comment: Just to be clear - you did not *actually* ask a question. To ask a question, you should have ended with something like: "Can someone tell me what is going on?" or "Why don't I get 'is a test'?"

Comment: Although, to be fair to you, it would be a very easy edit to fix your typo and add a little more text to turn it into a question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, `cut` doesn't split on space, only on tab.  If you tell it to split on space, then it won't split on tab.  Also, consecutive spaces or tabs will add empty fields to the set.

If you want to split on "any amount of any kind of whitespace", you're better off with `awk`:

```
echo "This is a test" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Also, you can replace `echo`...`|` with `<<<` in bash:

```
awk '{print $1}' <<<"This is a test"
```

Answer (score 8):

Use a space as the delimiter in the `cut` command:

```
echo "This is test" | cut -f 1 -d ' '
```

The default delimiter is a tab.  Take a look at the manpage for more details.